# find a date range from min and max date field

Tags: sql-server

I am trying to find the earliest instance of a date for a unique ID (unique ID has multiple rows of data with different dates) and then filter that result to find the data between years 2005 and 2010 using a subquery. I keep getting 'Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'group'':

```
Select *
from (select custnum, YEAR(min(Date_field)) as field1, Field2, field3, field4, field5   
        from table1
        group by custnum, field2, field3, field4, field5)
    having YEAR(min(Date_field)) between 2005 and 2010
```

Any Ideas?
Thanks for your help-

Comment: is custnum your uniqueid?

Comment: Try to get the `having YEAR(min(Date_field)) between 2005 and 2010` in the sub query.

Comment: You are using a sub-`select` w/o aliasing it, and your `having` clause is in the outer `select` while `group by` is in the sub-`select`. Yo are also referencing the sub-`select` Date_field in the outer `select` where it does not exist.

Comment: Custnum is the unique ID

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understood you correctly, you can use:

```
WITH CTE AS
(
    SELECT  custnum,
            Field2,
            Field3,
            Field4,
            Field5,
            Field1 = MIN(Date_Field) OVER(PARTITION BY custnum)
    FROM dbo.table1
)
SELECT *
FROM CTE
WHERE Field1 BETWEEN '20050101' AND '20101231';
```

Comment: @Gross And do you have rows where the minimum date for a `custnum` is between 2005 and 2010?. What's the `Date_Field` datatype?

Comment: yup- the data I have has multiple rows with same custnum with date ranges from 1982 to current. the date field type is datetime

Comment: sorry... I had modified the view this query hits to be active records which would not have a date pre-2010... I changed my view and the query worked- thank you very much!